# How to use JHipster and Hibernate Envers

Tags: jhipster

I am having trouble figuring out how to use Hibernate Envers and JHipster.

I am using PostgreSQL to store the data, and latest Jhipster 2.6.0
I just generated a JHipster application, with no modifications at all.
The User domain class extends the AbstractAuditingEntity class, which has the @Audited annotation, but when editing a user there's no t_user_aud table created in the database.

Is there any configuration needed in order to have Hibernate Envers saving modifications ?

Comment: we have a new module for audits, its not full fledged envers but a modified impl which gives pretty much same functionality with a nice UI https://jhipster.github.io/modules/marketplace/#/details/generator-jhipster-entity-audit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've got a github repository that shows how to add it for postgres for jhipster 2.6.0

Once you have your jhipster app generated, your postgres db created, entity generated (e.g. `yo jhipster:entity Foo`), and all previous db revision applied (run `mvn spring-boot:run` to make sure it runs previous db revisions).

**Warning:** 'spring-data-envers' causes breaks QueryDsl. (See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/issues/30). Furthermore, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/issues/33#issuecomment-108796022 says that the 'spring-data-envers' project is not a priority. Jhipster's already-included 'hibernate-envers' project lets you use envers without needing 'spring-data-envers'...so if you want to avoid QueryDsl problems, remove 'spring-data-envers' by skipping step 1 and 3.

1. Add spring-data-envers to your pom.xml.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
       <version>0.2.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add `@Audited` to your entity class in the domain package
3. Add `repositoryFactoryBeanClass=org.springframework.data.envers.repository.support.EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class` to your @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in DatabaseConfiguration.java (i.e. change the line so that it is something like `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.mycompany.myapp.repository", repositoryFactoryBeanClass=EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class`)
4. Add CustomRevisionEntity that extends DefaultRevisionEntity to add anything special to your revision tables (e.g. the login of who made the change)
5. Add CustomRevisionListener that implements RevisionListener to set the fields in your CustomRevisionEntity
6. `mvn liquibase:diff` will generate your changelog for adding auditing
7. Add the changelog to src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml

**Note**: liquibase-3.3.2 doesn't recognize INT4 for autoIncrement for postgres and would throw this
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown property autoIncrement for liquibase.datatype.core.UnknownType INT4`. You can change it to 'SERIAL' instead but you'll fight with further generated changelogs. I'd recommend upgrading to liquibase-3.3.3 (see https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/1602ddf1cf4968753e09a6858fc1580230a2fb44) but you'll also have to add `<liquibaseShouldRun>true</liquibaseShouldRun>` to the liquibase plugin configuration in your pom.xml.

**Note:** When you run your tests (using H2), H2 expects tinyint instead of smallint for the REVTYPE. Either ignore the tests or add something like this

```
<changeSet author="sdoxsee" id="1426529918864-0">
   <sql dbms="postgresql">CREATE DOMAIN "tinyint" AS smallint</sql>
</changeSet>
```

so that H2 will be happy and postgres will be happy. Otherwise you'll get

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in JHIPSTER.PUBLIC.T_FOO_AUD for column REVTYPE. Found: smallint, expected: tinyint`

when you run `mvn test`

8. `mvn spring-boot:run` again will apply the changelog
9. Create an entity through the running app
10. Open pgAdmin3 to see the audit table history!

Hope this helps.

I've included the source: https://github.com/sdoxsee/jhipster-app-envers

A helpful reference:

- http://hantsy.blogspot.ca/2013/11/auditing-with-hibernate-envers.html

Comment: It's working (had to change INT4 to SERIAL as you said). Thanks a lot for the detailed how-to.

Comment: The missing link for me is I had to change all instances of "SMALLINT" to "TINYINT" in the changelog as well as add the suggested SQL changeSet to the top of the changelog for my JUnit tests to work.

Comment: Second hurdle for using RevisionRepository, I had to change DatabaseConfiguration.java like so: @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.envers.repository", repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)

Answer (score 0):

We currently use the PersistentAuditEvent entity to save changes, and not the "normal" t_user_aud table.

This is because we add additional information (this is for security audits), compared to what Envers stores by default.

Comment: Thanks for the precisions about security audits needs.