# How to integrate spring-data-envers into my project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi I need to integrate this project available at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers into my project. I'm using spring-boot to manage all my configurations so I don't know how to add the line : 
into my project. I added the dependency spring-data-envers into my project but in order to use the repository that spring-data provides something else has to be done that I'm not seeing. Please give me a hint on how to do this with spring-boot

Comment: There's a little guide for spring-boot and spring-data-envers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29308586/1098564 note: spring-data-envers is not a well maintained project and conflicts with querydsl (if you use that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

We use this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAwareImpl")
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataRestConfig
    extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Repository itself has an [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/envers/sample) how to use it.

In general you need to add special `Hibernate` annotation `@Audited` to entities.
And your repository interfaces should extend additional interface `EnversRevisionRepository`.

Comment: My question was not how to use envers. I wanted to know how to add the jpa factory bean to my project. I found my answer. Apparently we have to use @EnableJpaRepositories annotation